# 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11

Tags: docker

When I running programing, on terminal show this error:
**2023-04-04T11:59:53.347052Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11**

What do I do?

TO add -o --watch in test don't solved.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Based on the error message only it's hard to do more than speculate.  (But that sort of sounds like a problem in a MySQL database container and not your application, possibly because multiple containers are trying to use the same underlying database storage.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.